# 文字列を「複数の区切り文字」で配列へ変換したい

Tags: php

下記のような文字列がある時、「。」もしくは「.」を区切り文字として、配列へ格納したい

```
$str = '今日は雨です。today is rainy.明日は晴れです。 It will be fine tomorrow.';
```

取得したい結果

```
$strAry[0] = '今日は雨です。';
$strAry[1] = 'today is rainy. ';
$strAry[2] = '明日は晴れです。';
$strAry[3] = 'It will be fine tomorrow.';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.preg-split.php)はいかがでしょうか。
参照: [複数のデリミタによるexplodeは何が速いか](https://qiita.com/khsk/items/ba5ebf62207f696ede53)

#### サンプルコード

```
<?php
$str = '今日は雨です。today is rainy.明日は晴れです。 It will be fine tomorrow.';
$strAry = preg_split("/[。\.]+/u", $str);
print_r($strAry);
?>
```

#### 出力結果

```
Array
(
    [0] => 今日は雨です
    [1] => today is rainy
    [2] => 明日は晴れです
    [3] =>  It will be fine tomorrow
    [4] => 
)
```

回答を書いていたところ、「。」と「.」のデリミタ自体が削られていることに気づきました。
デリミタを残す場合は単純に[preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.preg-match-all.php)で正規表現を使う対応が手っ取り早いように思います。

#### サンプルコード

```
<?php
$str = '今日は雨です。today is rainy.明日は晴れです。 It will be fine tomorrow.';
preg_match_all("/.+?[。\.]+/u", $str, $matches);
$strAry = $matches[0];
print_r($strAry);
?>
```

#### 出力結果

```
Array
(
    [0] => 今日は雨です。
    [1] => today is rainy.
    [2] => 明日は晴れです。
    [3] =>  It will be fine tomorrow.
)
```

Comment: リンク先を読んで実際に速度計測してみましたが、実行速度はほとんど変わりませんでした。正規表現だから必ずしも遅いとは限らないのですね。大変驚きました